# converting object to array then adding element to end of array then shuffle

Tags: php, arrays, apache, element

I figured it was time to ask because i have been working on this for over an hour.

I need to take an object and convert it to array - done
I need to add a new element to the end of the array as [9] => value  - ISSUE :(
I need to shuffle the array - done

Everything i try it always comes out like this

here is $wlist as the original class object

```
 CAPTCHA_CLASS_Wordlist Object
 (
[jsObjectList] => Array
    (
        [0] => providers
        [1] => chemical
        [2] => family
        [3] => supported
        [4] => urban
        [5] => produced
        [6] => continued
        [7] => stream
        [8] => administrative
    )

 )
```

which after conversion is this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => claim
        [1] => continued
        [2] => limit
        [3] => platform
        [4] => websites
        [5] => efforts
        [6] => dollars
        [7] => saint
        [8] => family
    )

[1] => water
)
```

it has to be [9] => value

i have even tried $arrayname[9] = $value and $arrayname[0][9] without success.. Even if i recreate the array inside a foreach i still have the same problem not being able to add the extra element at the end as key [9]

here is my code

```
      //convert object to array
     $convert = (array)$wlist;

     //now add the answer to it
     array_push($convert, $questanswer);

     //now shuffle

     $final = shuffle($convert);
```

$questanswer is just a text word like - house

thanks :)

Update:  here is what it looks like after stdClass

```
         //convert object to array
     $convert = (array)$wlist;

     //new stdClass and load it
     $nc = new stdClass;
     $nc->questanswer = $questanswer;

     //now add the answer to it
     array_push($convert[0], $nc);

     $finaloptions = shuffle($convert);


  Array
 (
  [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [questanswer] => hexagon
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => labor
        [1] => designated
        [2] => shops
        [3] => load
        [4] => fresh
        [5] => mass
        [6] => patch
        [7] => foot
        [8] => congress
    )

)
```

Comment: use `get_object_vars`

Comment: i think i tried that too but let me do it again its been a long day :)

Comment: yeah i still have the same problem, that just converts it, and i am adding the extra element after the conversion, so same issue

Comment: i guess i could turn the text value into an array and then merge but that would be the same i think

Comment: ok so your saying add the element before i convert it to an array right? So add the new value while its still an object right?

Comment: @dave it looks like `$convert` actually has an array within an array. It's that inner array you want to modify. See my answer

Comment: i updated my question with the results

Comment: I misunderstood your demand, You want to put the `$questanswer` at inner array, But i thought you need it like an Object to the main array, see my updated answer below.

Comment: @dave, no need to do the previous one, see the update answer. I was made a mistake, now its fine.

Comment: sorry for the confusion i get really freaked out on here cause im trying to make everyone happy :)

Answer (score 1):

`$convert` is a nested array. Use `array_push` on it's first element.

```
  //convert object to array
 $convert = (array)$wlist;

 //now add the answer to it
 array_push($convert[0], $questanswer);

 //now shuffle
 $final = shuffle($convert);
```

**Edit**

If you want to keep going this route, the answer is to return to your original code (eg, remove the `$nc = new StdClass...` stuff) except instead of `array_push($convert, $questanswer);` you use `array_push($conver[0], $questanswer);`

However, you might want to think about why you're doing this in the first place. If this `CAPTCHA_CLASS_Wordlist` is a class you've created, you should consider adding a function that you simply pass `$questanswer` to and that returns the desired array.

If this is your class definition file...

**CAPTCHA_CLASS_Wordlist.php**

```
<?php
class CAPTCHA_CLASS_Wordlist
{
    JsObjectList = [...];

    ... your other code ...

    public function getShuffledObjectListWithAnswer($questionAnswer)
    {
        $tempCopy = $this->JsObjectList;

         //now add the answer to it
         array_push($tempCopy, $questionAnswer);

         //now shuffle
         return shuffle($tempCopy);
    }
}
```

Now, you can use `$wlist` like this:

```
$final = $wlist->getShuffledObjectListWithAnswer($questanswer);
```

Done.

P.S. Of course, you wouldn't have to call the funciton `getShuffledObjectListWithAnswer`. It just seems like that would be descriptive. You who know better what it's actually supposed to be doing could come up with something better.

Comment: cant do that terminus because it returns this when using [0] array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: looks like you edited your code (but didn't update the code in the question. please do that). you'll have to do `array_push($convert[1], $questanswer);` now. Or revert your code

Answer (score 0):

Search for the index where you want to add the `$questanswer`. Let the index is `$search_index`.

[Check Online](https://3v4l.org/NbsIZ)

```
$search_index = 0;
$convert = (array) $wlist;

//now add the answer to it
array_push($convert[$search_index], $questanswer);
```

`$convert[$search_index]` is the array and also you can do it by using simple statement.

```
$convert[$search_index][] = $questanswer;
```

Comment: never considered using stdClass but ill read the docs and so i remember next time i need it.. thanks :) ill try it

Comment: @dave, If you make an desire output then we can better understand what actually you need , Delete your updated Question, that is not related to your demand i think.

Comment: didnt work either came out as array 0 0 and array 1 0-8  same as before

Comment: Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => myself
            [1] => labor
            [2] => fresh
            [3] => dollars
            [4] => rose
            [5] => quantity
            [6] => mass
            [7] => practices
            [8] => therapy
         )

    )

Comment: $searchindex = 0;

         //convert object to array
         $convert = (array)$wlist;
   
         //now add the answer to it
         $convert[$searchindex][] = $questanswer;

Answer (score 0):

i just did this.
seems to be working?

```
$wlist = new stdClass();
$wlist->property = 'Here we go';
$wlist->property1 = 'Here we go1';
$wlist->property11 = 'Here we go2';
var_dump($wlist);
$questanswer = 'bla';

//convert object to array
$convert = (array)$wlist;
var_dump($convert);
//now add the answer to it
array_push($convert, $questanswer);
var_dump($convert);
//now shuffle

$final = shuffle($convert);

var_dump($convert);
exit;
```

Comment: I think the reason this did not work brick is because of what im starting with and i do apologize i should have posted this as well.  I will update the post in just a moment so you can see

Comment: i saw your updated post.
where does the extra "water" comes from? :)

just get the array you want to process, place it in a variable then do all those other nasty things to it.

Comment: thank you all for your assistance greatly appreciated now i can go have some icecream lol :)